# What is Null Safety in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have heard of the new Dart null safety language feature (NNBD), currently the "**'non-nullable' experiment**". It is supposed to introduce ***non-nullable* by default**.

The feature specification can be [found here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/bdbef03e26047a1f59152f97d23663cf93a7108e/accepted/2.12/nnbd/feature-specification.md) and the language [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/110#issue-385073398).

How does it work and where can I try it?

Comment: IMHO Dart team is over doing it, just like Java forces us to catch all exception. The code became very noisy.

Comment: The first link is broken (404).

Answer (score 265, accepted):

## 1. Null safety / non-nullable (by default)

The null safety / non-nullable (by default), short NNBD, feature can currently be found at [nullsafety.dartpad.dev](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/).

Keep in mind that you can read the [full spec here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/bdbef03e26047a1f59152f97d23663cf93a7108e/accepted/2.12/nnbd/feature-specification.md) and [full roadmap here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/bdbef03e26047a1f59152f97d23663cf93a7108e/accepted/2.12/nnbd/roadmap.md). Now, sound null safety has also been [officially announced for Dart](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-sound-null-safety-defd2216a6f3).

---

### 2.1. What does non-nullable by default mean?

```dart
void main() {
  String word;
  print(word); // illegal

  word = 'Hello, ';
  print(word); // legal
}
```

As you can see above, a variable being *non-nullable **by default*** means that every variable that is declared normally **cannot** be `null`. Consequently, any operation accessing the variable before it has been assigned is illegal.
Additionally, assigning `null` to a non-nullable variable is also not allowed:

```dart
void main() {
  String word;
  
  word = null; // forbidden
  world = 'World!'; // allowed
}
```

#### 2.1.1. How does this help me?

If a variable is *non-nullable*, you can be sure that it is never `null`. Because of that, you never need to check it beforehand.

```dart
int number = 4;

void main() {
  if (number == null) return; // redundant

  int sum = number + 2; // allowed because number is also non-nullable
}
```

#### 2.1.2. Remember

Instance fields in classes **must be initialized** if they are not nullable:

```dart
class Foo {
  String word; // forbidden

  String sentence = 'Hello, World!'; // allowed
}
```

See `late` below to modify this behavior.

### 2.2. Nullable types (`?`)

You can use **nullable types** by appending a question mark `?` to a variable type:

```dart
class Foo {
  String word; // forbidden

  String? sentence; // allowed
}
```

A *nullable* variable does not need to be initialized before it can be used. It is initialized as `null` by default:

```dart
void main() {
  String? word;
  
  print(word); // prints null
}
```

#### 2.2.2. `!`

Appending **`!`** to any variable `e` will throw a **runtime error** if `e` is null and otherwise convert it to a **non-nullable** value `v`.

```dart
void main() {
  int? e = 5;
  int v = e!; // v is non-nullable; would throw an error if e were null

  String? word;
  print(word!); // throws runtime error if word is null

  print(null!); // throws runtime error
}
```

### 2.3. `late`

The keyword `late` can be used to mark variables that will be **initialized later**, i.e. not when they are declared but when they are accessed. This also means that we can have non-nullable *instance fields* that are initialized later:

```dart
class ExampleState extends State {
  late final String word; // non-nullable

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // print(word) here would throw a runtime error
    word = 'Hello';
  }
}
```

Accessing `word` before it is initialized will throw a runtime error.

#### 2.3.1. `late final`

Final variables can now also be marked late:

```dart
late final int x = heavyComputation();
```

Here `heavyComputation` will only be called once `x` is accessed. Additionally, you can also declare a `late final` without an initializer, which is the same as having just a `late` variable, but it can only be assigned once.

```dart
late final int x;
// w/e
x = 5; // allowed
x = 6; // forbidden
```

Note that all *top-level* or *static* variables with an initializer will now be evaluated `late`, no matter if they are `final`.

### 2.4. `required`

Formerly an **annotation** (`@required`), now built-in as a modifier. It allows to mark any named parameter (for functions or classes) as `required`, which makes them non-nullable:

```dart
void allowed({required String word}) => null;
```

This also means that if a parameter should be **non-nullable**, it needs to be marked as `required` or have a default value:

```dart
void allowed({String word = 'World'}) => null;

void forbidden({int x}) // compile-time error because x can be null (unassigned)
    =>
    null;
```

Any other named parameter has to be **nullable**:

```dart
void baz({int? x}) => null;
```

### 2.5. `?[]`

The null aware `?[]` operator was added for the index operator `[]`:

```dart
void main() {
  List<int>? list = [1, 2, 3];

  int? x = list?[0]; // 1
}
```

See also [this article about the syntax decision](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-nullability-syntax-decision-a-b-or-a-b-d827259e34a3).

#### 2.5.1. `?..`

The cascade operator now also has a new null aware operator: `?..`.

It causes the following cascade operations to only be executed if the recipient is **not null**. Therefore, the `?..` has to be the first cascade operator in a cascade sequence:

```dart
void main() {
  Path? path;

  // Will not do anything if path is null.
  path
    ?..moveTo(3, 4)
    ..lineTo(4, 3);

  // This is a noop.
  (null as List)
    ?..add(4)
    ..add(2)
    ..add(0);
}
```

---

### 2.6. `Never`

***The following explanation sucks. Read ["Top and bottom" from "Understanding null safety"](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#top-and-bottom)*** for a good one.

To avoid confusion: this is not something that developers have to worry about. I want to mention it for the sake of completeness.

`Never` is going to be a type like the previously existing [`Null`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Null-class.html) (**not `null`**) defined in `dart:core`. Both of these classes cannot be extended, implemented, or mixed in, so they are not intended to be used.

Essentially, `Never` means that no type is allowed and `Never` itself cannot be instantiated.
Nothing but `Never` in a  `List<Never>` satisfies the generic type constraint of the list, which means that it *has to be **empty***. `List<Null>`, however, can contain `null`:

```dart
// Only valid state: []
final neverList = <Never>[
  // Any value but Never here will be an error.
  5, // error
  null, // error

  Never, // not a value (compile-time error)
];

// Can contain null: [null]
final nullList = <Null>[
  // Any value but Null will be an error.
  5, // error
  null, // allowed

  Never, // not a value (compile-time error)
  Null, // not a value (compile-time error)
];
```

Example: the compiler will infer `List<Never>` for an **empty** `const List<T>`.
`Never` is not supposed to be used by programmers as far as I am concerned. ([I was wrong](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#never-for-unreachable-code)).

## 3. Learn more

You can read the [official article on sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).
Furthermore as mentioned at the beginning, you can [play with it on DartPad](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/).

Comment: Can you give some scenarios where `Never` can be used?

Comment: We have actually decided to use "?[]" for the null-aware index operator instead of "?.[]". The latter is a little more complex grammatically, but it's what users want.

Comment: @RamsesAldama I have added something. The specification I linked to mentions more.

Comment: @munificent The spec and experiment are still outdated then; thank you for pointing out.

Comment: It should be pointed out that `late final` on a member or instance variable only checks at runtime. It is not possible to check for that at development time or compile time because of the halting problem. So you will not get IDE help with it.

Comment: @Graham Yes, of course. This applies to numerous operations, e.g. using a `late` variable in general before its initialization.

Comment: Is there a way to compile code now with non-nullables by default, or the Dartpad is the only place where this can be tried?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: Thanks!, can you explain an object with API data receipt and its format? the best way

Comment: @RamsesAldama Never has no values and can never be success and executed

Comment: Four links are broken: The first, second, third, and last link are broken (*"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at nullsafety.dartpad.dev."*, *"404"*, *"404"*, *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at nullsafety.dartpad.dev."* respectively).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for pointing it out. Yeah, null safety has now been fully integrated into Dartpad. How would you go about adjusting the answer?

Answer (score -2):

If you want this field required, then use the *required* keyword. Otherwise, you only need to add "?". Like this:

```
const phonefield({
    Key? key, required this.onchanged,
}) : super(key: key);

final  ValueChanged<String>onchanged;
```