# How do I use Non-nullable By Default in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the [NNBD Dart feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60068435/6509751) in my Flutter app today, but I could not find out how to use it.

If I try to use `int?` et al., I get the following error:

```
This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### With Flutter 2

As of Flutter 2 (and Dart 2.12), null safety is the new **default**. This means that by specifying the following SDK constraint:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

You automatically opt into null safety.

### Pre Flutter 2

You need to make sure that your Dart SDK version constraint is `2.9.0` in your `pubspec.yaml` file (use `flutter channel master`):

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.0-8.0 <3.0.0"
```

Now, you can add an `analysis_options.yaml` file next to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

You should not expect compilation to succeed as of now.

Answer (score 2):

change sdk version on given below

```
 environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

then, run flutter pub get