# Is there "!." operator in dart (flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter source files contains many times code similar to this:

```
 @override
  double computeMinIntrinsicWidth(double height) {
    if (child != null)
      return child!.getMinIntrinsicWidth(height);
    return 0.0;
  }
```

Please explain "!." I can't find it on list of dart operators.

Comment: Probably something like "null assertion" operator?

Comment: There is conditional member access operator "?." in dart,  but I'm asking about "!.".

Comment: Ok. I think maybe somewhere in code there is overloaded operator "!", so child!.getMinIntrinsicWidth(height) is in fact child.operator!().getMinIntrinsicWidth(height) ...

Comment: Related SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068435

Answer (score 3):

A postfix exclamation mark (!) takes the expression on the left and casts it to its underlying non-nullable type. So it changes:

```
String toString() {
  if (code == 200) return 'OK';
  return 'ERROR $code ${(error as String).toUpperCase()}';
}
```

to something like this:

```
String toString() {
  if (code == 200) return 'OK';
  return 'ERROR $code ${error!.toUpperCase()}';
}
```

You can read more about null safety in [this document](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

It's the "[(not)null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator)" which becomes part of Dart with the Null Safety feature in the next release.