# How do you opt out of null safety in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

As of Dart `2.12.0`, [null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068436/6509751) is enabled by default.

The ["Enabling null safety" section on `dart.dev`](https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety) states the following:

> Set the SDK constraints to require a language version that has null safety support. For example, your pubspec.yaml file might have the following constraints:
>
> ```yaml
> environment:
>  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
> ```

So now that it is enabled by default, how do we opt out of null safety and write code like before **when our SDK constraint has `>=2.12.0-0`**?
We might want to require a Dart version like this for a different language feature but not want to use NNBD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to **not** use NNBD in a file that uses Dart `>=2.12.0=0`.
Thus, you only have two options to opt out of null safety:

#### Opting out file by file

Even if your minimum SDK constraint is `>=2.12.0=0`, you can opt-out single files using [per-library language version selection](https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution#per-library-language-version-selection).

At the very top of your file **before any imports etc.**, you can specify the Dart version the whole file should use:

```dart
// @dart=2.11
import 'dart:math';
...
```

This way, that file will be able to opt-out of null safety by using Dart 2.11.

#### Lower the SDK constraint

If you lower Dart SDK constraint is below `2.12.0-0`, you are by default opting out of null safety:

```yaml
environment:
 sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

---

Learn more by reading through [the unsound null safety article on `dart.dev`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#migrating-incrementally).