# Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

When upgrading a Flutter package for null safety I got this error when running `flutter test`:

```
Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
// @dart = 2.8
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to load "/Users/xxxxx/test/text_test.dart":
  Compilation failed
```

The answer was right there but I was still confused for a while, so I'm adding my answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem also occurs when you have a mixed-version code i.e. the code is not fully migrated to sound null safety. To run the app:

1. **Using IDE**

   Add `// @dart=2.9` at the top in your `main.dart` file and run the app using the Play ► icon.

   ```dart
   // @dart=2.9
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   void main() {
     //...
   }
   ```
2. **Using command line**

   ```
   flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
   ```

   or to be specific (say in chrome)

   ```
   flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety
   ```

Comment: I'm changing the selected answer to this one because of popular vote.

Answer (score 8):

To solve your problem, remove the following line from **text_test.dart**:

```dart
// @dart = 2.8
```

This annotation is for opting out of sound null safety (see [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#migrating-incrementally) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916946/how-do-you-opt-out-of-null-safety-in-dart)). However, libraries (packages) are not allowed to do that if they want to be sound null safe.