# Non-nullable instance field '_description' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

"Non-nullable instance field '_description' must be initialized."

Starting with version 2.12.0, Flutter always displays messages like this, how to solve this problem without downloading the version?

Searching, I saw that I could put the "?" next to the type:

String? _Description;

But I didn't really understand what this does and at the same time it generates other errors in my project

Comment: This might help - https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Refer this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068435/what-is-null-safety-in-dart