# Error: The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<int>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

i am this as i convert to Null- safety, and i keep getting this error

[image: error]

here is my code

```
try {
      final AuthorizationResult appleResult =
          await TheAppleSignIn.performRequests([
        AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope?.email, Scope?.fullName])
      ]);
      if (appleResult.error != null) {
        // handle errors from Apple here
      }

      final AuthCredential credential = OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
        accessToken:
            String.fromCharCodes(appleResult.credential!.authorizationCode),//here the error coming out.... i have also try Uint8List.fromList but still showing the error
        idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleResult.credential!.identityToken),//here the error coming out.... i have also try Uint8List.fromList but still showing the error
      );
      final firebaseResult = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      users = firebaseResult.user;
      if (users == null) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return false;
    }
```

i have also try

**Uint8List.from()**

Comment: Your problem is that `String.fromCharCodes` expects an `Iterable<int>`, but `(appleResult.credential!.authorizationCode` and `appleResult.credential!.identityToken` are `Uint8List?`.  Using `Uint8List.from` won't help you because that works in the wrong direction.  You need to check that your `Uint8List?` values aren't null first.

Comment: how will i check the ? Uint8List? i have post my code, please can restructure the code @jamesdlin

Comment: If you know that should not be null, then you can use `.authorizationCode!` and `.identityToken!`.  Otherwise you will need to specify a default value to use if they are null (e.g. `.authorizationCode ?? []`) or add explicit checks.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60068435/.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

Your `Uint8List?` is nullable and `Iterable<int>` is non-nullable so you can't assign nullable to non-nullable.

**Solutions:**

1. Provide a default value if `Unit8List?` can be `null`.

   ```dart
   Iterable<int> iterable = yourUint8List ?? [];
   ```
2. Use bang operator if `Uint8List?` can't be `null`.

   ```
   Iterable<int> iterable = yourUint8List!;
   ```