# Error Assigning 'GoogleSignInAccount?' to 'GoogleSignInAccount' in Flutter Authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm integrating Google sign-in with Firebase authentication in my Flutter app. When trying to assign the result of `GoogleSignIn().signIn(`) to a `GoogleSignInAccount` variable, I encounter a type mismatch error. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  return {
    "email": googleUser.email,
    "photoUrl": googleUser.photoUrl,
    "credentials": await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential),
  };
}

Future<bool> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return true;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
    print(e.code);
    return false;
  }
}



Future<bool> signUpWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return true;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
    print(e.code);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Flutter's suggestion is:**

> A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'GoogleSignInAccount'.

I've attempted to cast the variable to the non-nullable type but still face issues. How can I correctly assign a value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount' in this context?

Comment: To start off, **where** does flutter appear to think the problem is? Also, **do you understand why** there is a problem?

Comment: Hint: do you expect that `await GoogleSignIn().signIn();` will always give you an account? What if the credentials are wrong, for example? What do you think should happen in the rest of the code, in that case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Null Safety in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068435/what-is-null-safety-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, `GoogleSignIn().signIn()` returns you `GoogleSignInAccount?` that means it could be `null` and you can't pass it to variable type `GoogleSignInAccount`. You need to change `googleUser`'s type to `GoogleSignInAccount?`.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

after that you need to change your return map in `signInWithGoogle` to this:

```
final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

...
return {
    "email": googleUser?.email ?? '',
    "photoUrl": googleUser?.photoUrl ?? '',
    "credentials": await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential),
  };
```

what I did is that use `?` on `googleUser`, and set the default value (`' '`) incase that googleUser was `null`. you need to repeat this for `credential` too and provide it default value that good for it incase it get `null` too.